# How to Disable the feeds for a site: Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, feed

I have a site built in wordpress, whenever i click on a menu link continuously for two three times it takes me to a link www.mysite.com/feed. why this is happening and how i can overcome this issue.

I have tried with some plugin to to restrict the feeds but they have only redirect it to 404 page.

Any help will be appropriated

Answer (score 0):

Open your functions.php located within your themes folder and add the following code:

```
function fb_disable_feed() {
wp_die( __('No feed available,please visit our <a href="'. get_bloginfo('url') .'">homepage</a>!') );
}

add_action('do_feed', 'fb_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rdf', 'fb_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss', 'fb_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss2', 'fb_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_atom', 'fb_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss2_comments', 'fb_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_atom_comments', 'fb_disable_feed', 1);
```

this should work :D

Comment: it will also work for RSS feeds? right now i am facing issue with RSS feeds

Comment: Yeah it Works. But actually i want to disable it totally from the site. site never ever goes to these feeds in any situation. Also can you please tell me why my site is going to these feeds what is the reason behind this. @Awah Hammad